# how to change VIM's default keyboard shortcut for toggle windows?

Tags: vim

In vim, the switch-window-key , `<C-w><C-w>` (press 2 times), is not comfortable to me, so  I want to change it to `<C-Tab>`. What I do: adding `map <C-w><C-w> <C-Tab>` to the config file `~/.vimrc`, but it does not work as if shortcut `<C-Tab>` has been used.
I'm not sure whether `<C-w><C-w>` is the right representation of the toggle window command,either. So how can I make it work pressing `<C-Tab>`?

Comment: Don’t use `map`, you need `nnoremap` here. And the ordering (first what is mapped, then what is it mapped to) is wrong, you actually have the opposite. I would also hardly suggest to have left control on CapsLock, this way `<C-w><C-w>` and almost any `<C-letter>` mapping is far easier to hit, but `<C-Tab>` will be far harder (without removing hands from the base raw, while using browser it is just as easy as I don’t have hands in that position).

Answer (score 3):

First, the order of your mapping is wrong, you should do:

```
<map command> <desired shortcut> <action>
```

so, you should write your mapping like that:

```
map <C-Tab> <C-w><C-w>
```

and most certainly use `nnoremap` instead of `map`.

But `<C-Tab>` is an unreliable shortcut that won't work in many context so you should avoid it. I'd advise you to use `<leader>` (`:help mapleader`) or some other - better supported -- shortcut.

Note that `<C-w><C-w>` is not that bad: you just press `Ctrl` and hit `ww`. That's not that big of a deal.

Comment: You could also use `<C-h`/`j`/`k`/`l>` instead which can be very useful, like for example here: https://github.com/Greduan/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/vimrc#L294

Answer (score 0):

it's better to map it that way, so you can toggle between windows with more flexibility:

```
map <c-j> <c-w>j "move up                                                      
map <c-k> <c-w>k "down                                                                 
map <c-l> <c-w>l "right                                                                  
map <c-h> <c-w>h "left
```